# block access to subfolder, redirect all wildcard subfolders to same name subdomain

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

i have created subdomains to all folders of a domain:

```
www.some_domain_url.com/www1   to  www1.some_domain_url.com
www.some_domain_url.com/www2   to  www2.some_domain_url.com
www.some_domain_url.com/www3   to  www3.some_domain_url.com
```

How can I block user access to all subfolders and auto redirect them to corresponding subdomain?

For example when user go to www.some_domain_url.com/www1  ,the url www1.some_domain_url.com appears

and also, how can this be achieved for wildcard?

Thank you!!

Comment: Could you please post some sample of urls which you want to redirect/rewrite to which url?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect, you can setup something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/www1/ http://www1.some_domain_url.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/www2/ http://www2.some_domain_url.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^/www3/ http://www3.some_domain_url.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you but how can you do it with wide card subdomain?

Comment: I'm not sure this works because I've never done it and I can't test it now, but you can give it a try:
RewriteRule ^\/([^\/]+) http://$1.some_domain_url.com/ or you can try with RewriteRule ^\/([^\/]+) http://%1.some_domain_url.com/